# Simplify ${\nabla}_\theta J(\theta) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1 + e^{-y_i \theta^\intercal x_i}} e^{-y_i \theta^\intercal x_i}({-y_i x_i})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, gradient-descent

I had a lecture today where we talked about gradient descent, and my teacher wrote the following expression on the board:

${\nabla}_\theta J(\theta) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1 + e^{-y_i \theta^\intercal x_i}} e^{-y_i \theta^\intercal x_i}({-y_i x_i})$

Which he then simplified to

$=> -\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{y_i x_i}{1 + e^{-y_i \theta^\intercal x_i}}$

I've been trying to redo this myself without skipping steps but this part I don't manage to figure it out.

Comment: Are brackets missing around $(-y_ix_i)$? If yes the simplification contains a mistake and should read$- \frac{1}{n}\sum_{I=1}^{n}\frac{y_ix_i}{1+e^{+y_i \Theta^{\top}x_i}}$

Comment: Yes! Edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just assume there is a small mistake in your question and put parenthesis around the last term. I think your teacher made a small mistake:
\begin{align}
\nabla_{\Theta}J(\theta) &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+e^{-y_i \theta^{\top}x_i}} e^{-y_i \theta^{\top}x_i}(-y_ix_i)\\ &= 
 -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{y_ix_i}{(1+e^{-y_i \theta^{\top}x_i})e^{y_i \theta^{\top}x_i}}\\ 
&= - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{y_ix_i}{e^{y_i \theta^{\top}x_i}+ e^0}
\\
&= - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{y_ix_i}{1 +e^{y_i \theta^{\top}x_i}}
\end{align}

Notice the positive exponent of $e$.

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much, easy and clear to follow! :)